# Configure Dynamic Web project on eclipse to use Bower or NPM

Tags: eclipse, servlets, npm, bower

Several JS libs are using Bower or NPM as package manager. Is it possible and if it's so, how can I configure my Dynamic Web project to use one of these two package managers.

Comment: Did you succeed to setup such project?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't.

Comment: The closest thing I found is https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin, which is "A Maven plugin that downloads/installs Node and NPM locally, runs NPM install, Grunt, Gulp and/or Karma."